# Flow control with Jetty WebSocket

Tags: websocket, jetty

I'm trying to use WebSockets as an application protocol (no browsers here) and am running into issues with flow control...  I'm currently using Jetty 9.1.0.RC0 with a WebSocketServlet, and a @WebSocket.

The first case is where messages are coming in faster than I can deal with them.  In this case I want to suspend reading from that socket and let TCP backpressure do its thing.  This has worked great in previous applications (non websocket of course).  I thought that Session.suspend() might do what I want, but it appears to have no affect, and the token returned is null.

Is there a way to suspect reading?  As its a nio based connector, Jetty is going to keep reading the frames and buffering them until I can handle them, and I'd rather just pause reading than have to introduce some flow control messages.

My second case is where I'm sending websocket messages to a connected client - this might be a browser, but not always...  It appears I can get some flow control by using the sendStringByFuture methods, but is there a way to get a callback when the future is done, rather than having to wait on it or poll it?

As I already have jetty embedded and am using it for SpringMVC it would be nice if I could get the flow control I need on it, to avoid running something like Netty on another port.

Thanks.

Comment: The Session.suspend() fault is a bug in Jetty WebSocket.  It will be fixed for 9.1 final.

Comment: Will there also be an isReady equivalent to determine if a write would not block, like can be done for http streaming?

Comment: `Session.suspend()` is for read suspension, not write.

Comment: Note that WebSocket can exist inside other protocols that mux and perform their own flow control (WebSocket in SPDY, HTTP/1.1 + mux-extension, or WebSocket in HTTP/2), so exposing write-based flow control in a WebSocket API is generally viewed as short term thinking that becomes increasingly more difficult to support as time goes on.

Comment: As I'm streaming stuff out to my websocket clients, at some point I need to know if they are backed up (being buffered in jetty rather than making it out to the wire), so my application can do the correct thing.  Would Jetty way be to use sendXByFuture, and check the status of the future on the next send?

Comment: Bring this conversation to the jetty-users list (not appropriate for stackoverflow)

Comment: a feature request for Session.isReady() has been opened at https://bugs.eclipse.org/420945

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty and JSR APIs do have an aysnchronous call back style of write.  In Jetty it is:
    sendBytes(ByteBuffer data, WriteCallback callback)
and the JSR API is:
    sendBinary(ByteBuffer data, SendHandler handler)

both have text message equivalents.   But there are some problems with both of these.    Firstly if the callback is used for flow control, then the callback will "be notified when the message has been transmitted".     That is not optimal for high throughput as it means that the sending of the next message will always wait until the previous message has been transmitted, giving no opportunity to aggregate multiple messages into single write.

If subsequent calls to sentBytes or sendBinary do not wait for the callback, then they can queue up multiple frames that will be efficiently transmitted, but then the problem is that there is no back pressure on sending, so the internal queue can possibly grow forever.

One "solution" is to have a limited queue size, but then you get problems with a supposedly async call to sendBytes suddenly blocks!

I think the solution is to have an alternative form of callback for sends that are called once the message is queued to be transmitted, but not actually transmitted.   Once this callback is called, then any buffers passed can be reused/recycled and another call and another call to sendBytes/sendBinary can be made.

Perhaps something like:

public interface QueuedWriteCallback extends WriteCallback
  {
    writeQueued();
  }

and for the JSR:

public interface QueuedSendHandler extends SendHandler
  {
    onQueued();
  }